# How do I quickly check the layout for different browser sizes?

Tags: html, css

Far too often after writing HTML+CSS and looking at the outcome in Chrome, I drag the corner of the window tocheck how it will look for other sizes and aspect ratios.

I could right-click, choose `inspect`, click `Toggle device toolbar` and select a few sizes for mobile phones.

But this is even less effective than dragging the browser's corner, plus I'd like to see the view for someone whose browser is closer to a modest 1024x768 than the lavish sizes a browser has on my desktop.

How do I quickly check the layout for different browser sizes?

For concreteness, here is an MWE. How can I, with a few keystrokes, confirm that the background color does indeed change (without resizing the browser window)?

```css
html {
  background-color: #eee;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  html {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  html {
    background-color: #aaa;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just grab [an extension with hotkey shortcuts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh?hl=en).

Comment: @ChrisW. Seriously? Is this functionality so exotic it is not built into Chrome and requires an extension? 
In any case, the one you suggest gets me to `Window Resizer [] is blocked by the administrator.`
Is there an option for those who cannot install extensions?

Comment: If you're running your website on your local host, try run them through [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/)

Comment: @Vrokipal Sorry I have no good answer for you there. I'd think that if you already f12'd open the developer tools it should definitely be something already baked in too but I know personally I haven't found it beyond [responsive mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/#responsive) with some preset sizes you can add. Maybe someone will come along and teach us both something new :)